# resetting html5 slider failed

Tags: jquery, html

After a lot of tries I ask for help.  I have this slider

```
<input autocomplete="off" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50" class="myslider" id="mysliderID-slider" data-fieldid="something">
<input type="text" class="mysliderinput" name="myname" id="mysliderID" value="0">
```

Now I want to reset this slider with this code

```
$('#mysliderID').val(0);
$('#mysliderID').attr('value',0);
$('#mysliderID-slider').val(0);
$('#mysliderID-slider').attr('value',0);
```

The value field in sourcecode will be reset to 0, but the slider himself is at the old position and in the input field i already see the old value.

What caused that or what I do wrong ?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `$('#mysliderID').attr(0);` will cause an error:

> TypeError: name.toLowerCase is not a function

See http://api.jquery.com/attr/ on how to use `.attr()`

Working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/5mhywjva/1/

```
$('#button').on('click', function() {
    $('#mysliderID').val(0);
    $('#mysliderID-slider').val(0);
});
```

---

```
<input autocomplete="off" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50" class="myslider" id="mysliderID-slider" data-fieldid="something">
<input type="text" class="mysliderinput" name="myname" id="mysliderID" value="10">

<button id="button">
Reset
</button>
```

Comment: sorry mistake by typing, i've update the code as it is. Please have a look. The way you write wont work for me - i trie this alreay. I dont understand it...

Comment: @RainerS Well the question still misses something then because as you can see it works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/f98ubq51/ If you can, try to build a jsfiddle example that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: may it is so. Now the slider will reset, correctly, but the displayed value of the input field is not updated. The value="1234" is correctly updated, what can caused this?

Comment: I don't know. Sadly you are not sharing your current code with us and I don't like to guess :(. I can just keep referencing to my jsfiddle where everything works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

you can use onchange event on slider to update value of text box    `<input autocomplete="off" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50" class="myslider" id="mysliderID-slider" data-fieldid="something" onchange="update()">`

```
function update() {
    $('#mysliderID').attr('value',$('#mysliderID-slider').val());
}
```